# CSS animation progress bar runs from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have this CSS animation the progress bar runs from the top of the screen to the bottom I want to reverse this so it runs from the bottom of the screen to the top.

```css
.meter9 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.meter9 span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress9 {
  background-color: #d6185e;
  animation: progressBar1 3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes progressBar1 {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="meter9">
  <span style="width:100%;"><span class="progress9"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you could anchor the element on bottom of its parent via position relative + absolute or using flexbox with justify-content: flex-end and flex-direction: column. It depends on your markup.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi I have added further code to show the markup - any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set :

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

to .meter9 span, so it will be at the bottom, and it will grow to top.

```css
.meter9 { 
  top:0%;
  left: 80%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: transparent;
}

.meter9 span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress9 {
  background-color: #d6185e;
  animation: progressBar1 3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
}

@keyframes progressBar1 {
  0% { height: 0; }
  100% { height: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="meter9">
    <span style="width:100%;"><span class="progress9"></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use `display: flex;` + `align-items: flex-end;` Items will be then positioned at the end of the container. You can also easily create multiple *progress bars* with this approach. See the example below.

```css
.meter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; /*flexbox*/
  align-items: flex-end; /*bottom to top*/
}

.progress {
  flex: 1; /*grow*/
  animation: progressBar ease-in-out forwards;
}

.progress:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.progress:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #51cf66;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.progress:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #339af0;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes progressBar {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="meter">
  <span class="progress"></span>
  <span class="progress"></span>
  <span class="progress"></span>
</div>
```